# Is there a way to use excel's VLOOKUP with multiple criteria?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm attempting to create an aggregate of data that looks at a list with a lot of duplication of items and compiles a total number that the duplication appears, and a unique value associated with the most recent one (its date)

So the Data looks something like this:

[image: So the Data looks something like this]

I want to be able to create a line item "Apple" that can in the next column tell me that for "Farm", apple appears twice.

And then I want the next line to tell me the last time "Apple" appeared with "Farm" was on 4/24/2018.

I believe I've done the first step in telling me how many times "Apple" appears for "Farm" by using a =COUNTIFS function, one set of criteria for a "farm" criteria on column B, and the second set of criteria for "Apple" on column A, but how do I look through the list and give me only one date for simultaneously only apple and only farm? I've looked into Vlookup, but it's limited to only one criteria.

The results should tabulate this out like this:

[image: The results should tabulate this out like this]

Comment: A pivot table will get you exactly what you want (though a slightly different format). You'll be able to show the counts of the items, the aggregate dates, and all of it. Just select your original data table and create a pivot table from it. There are plenty of tutorials to show how.

Comment: I'm aware that a pivot table solves some of these issues, but I found no way for a pivot table to cleanly provide me for the Farm_last field anything that resembles a single date to correlate to the corresponding FRUIT. I can either have it sum the dates, or show me a list of all dates for the fruits, or apply other arithmetic to the dates, but I can't say "only show me one that meets this criteria, and disregard the rest."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **Farm_count** please try this formula: `=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$5=A10)*($B$2:$B$5=LEFT($B$9,LEN($B$9)-(LEN($B$9)-FIND("_",$B$9)+1))))`

[image]

For **Farm_last** please use this array formula: `=MAX(IF(($A$2:$A$5=A10)*($B$2:$B$5=LEFT($B$9,LEN($B$9)-(LEN($B$9)-FIND("_",$B$9)+1))),$C$2:$C$5,""))`

End by pressing **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**

[image]

Comment: I'm getting a #Value! error in excel using your Farm_last expression. Can you explain to me what the logic here is? I'm looking at LEN() and FIND() and I'm not really getting an understanding the fundamental of why you're counting strings or looking for the position of other strings. Is that to make it in some ways a repeatable structure so it can always look at the header and derive the source type it's going to be looking for? If that's the reason I still don't really see how that's being accomplished.

Comment: I was unaware of the ctrl-shift-enter neccessity here. I don't normally work with array objects as functions in excel so my apologies there. This solution does in fact work. I am having difficulty extrapolating this to my actual data set, though.

Comment: You can provide a sample about your actual dat set.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**How it works:**

1. In **B8** write this formula  & Fill down.

   `=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$5=A8),--($B$2:$B$5=$C$6))`
2. To find **last time "Apple" appeared with "Farm,"** write this array
   formula in **C8** & finish with *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*.

`{=INDEX($C$2:$C$5,SMALL(IF($C$6=$B$2:$B$5,ROW($B$2:$B$5)-ROW($B$2)+1),2))}`

3. To **find appearance Date for Orange in Farm,** write this array formula
   in **C9** & finish with *Ctrl+shift+Enter*.

`{=INDEX($C$2:$C$5,SMALL(IF($C$6=$B$2:$B$5,ROW($B$2:$B$5)-ROW($B$2)+1),1))}`

**Note,**

- *Cell C6 has Farm.*
- *Adjust cell references in formula as needed.*

Comment: This works for both, but what's the reason for the ROW() functions here? I'm not really understanding the hows or whys of this and extrapolating it into my dataset is confusing me. And is there a macro way to ctrl-shift-enter on multiple functions? In the data I'm actually working with I have to apply this logic several thousand times and I'm dreading needing to F2 into each one and Ctrl-Shift-Entering each one in order to apply it.

Comment: I also just realized I have no idea how the index function is determining the correct fruit type. I see the 1 and 2 is different. It's contained within your small function. I don't really understand what's happening here or how this could work if I expand the data set to include more fruit types.

Comment: These 3 formulas are better that MACRO, will work for even large data range & the key part is whether it's working for the issue or not,, yes It's working properly, as you also wrote, This works for both.

Comment: Yes this can be accomplished by using MACRO also, but since It was not specified that you may think for it so that the Formulation has been shown. Since it's working for that data range Row 2 to 5 to determine the last appearance of Apple in Farm so that an array function is required. `=ROW($B$2:$B$5)-ROW($B$2)+1` returns 1 that is the first record position`B2` in the data range `B2:B5` and this range is working with `SMALL`, and `+2` at last is value of `K` is in fact the Second occurrence that is `April/23`.

Comment: The solution is better than`VLOOKUP` & faster too.